# Cartthrob php orders when logged in

Tags: cartthrob, php-errors, checkout

EE 2.7.2
CT 2.5

I'm working on a live cartthrob site that I inherited and there are php errors on the checkout pages, but only when logged in. Is there a known fix for this?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 3784

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 3784

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Template.php

Line Number: 3784

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 809

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /path/to/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

Comment: Is seeing these errors only when logged in not the default behaviour? 

Is the libraries/template.php in EE core or cart throb itself?

Otherwise product options and order items are held in arrays (off the top of my head). Could there be an ambiguous array key?

Answer (score 1):

I would update Cartthrob to V2.6 if i were you Sean!